# Pandas, Numpy: How to Speed up row iteration with inner loop?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following data set, and I am calculating the `Net Forecast` column based on the rest.

The logic implemented is,

- If there is an `Order` < 0 for a Part, we add it with `Gross Forecast` in the same row, i.e., `0`.
- If the `Order` is not yet positive from the above calculation, we add it with `Gross Forecast` of previous week, i.e, `-1`.
- We carry on with this loop in the following order `[0, -1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]`, i.e, go back 3 Weeks and go forward 3 weeks, until the `Order` is 0.
- If there are no more weeks, or if the order is not fulfilled, we then transfer the calculation we did with the `Gross Forecast` column to the `Net Forecast` column.

```
   Part  Week  Gross Forecast  Orders  Net Forecast
0     A     1              10       0            10
1     A     2               5       0             0
2     A     3              30       0             0
3     A     4              20       0             0
4     A     5              10     -70             0
5     A     6              50       0             0
6     A     7               5     -60             0
7     A     8              30       0            20
8     Z     1              10       0            10
9     Z     2               5       0           -15
10    Z     3              10       0             0
11    Z     4              30       0             0
12    Z     5              30     -90             0
```

I was able to recreate the logic, but it is really slow using standard `iterrows`. Is it possible to vectorize this solution using Pandas and Numpy?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    "Part": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"],
    "Week": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "Gross Forecast": [10, 5, 30, 20, 10, 50, 5, 30, 10, 5, 10, 30, 30],
    "Orders": [0, 0, 0, 0, -70, 0, -60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -90],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Create Net Forecast column
df["Net Forecast"] = df["Gross Forecast"]

for i, row in df.iterrows():

    k = 0
    order = 0
    inventory = 0
    index_list = [0, -1, -2, -3, 1, 2, 3]

    if df.loc[i, "Orders"] != 0:
        order = df.loc[i, "Orders"]

        for j in index_list:

            try:

                if order < 0 and (df.loc[i, "Part"] == df.loc[i + j, "Part"]):
                    order = order + df.loc[i + j, "Net Forecast"]
                    df.loc[i + j, "Net Forecast"] = 0
                    k = j
                else:
                    break

            except KeyError:
                break

        df.loc[i + k, "Net Forecast"] = order

print(df)
```

Comment: `vectorize` in the `numpy` sense means to use whole-array operations, where (conceptually) all rows are evaluated independently and in-parallel (or at least in any order).  You are evaluating the rows in a certain order, with one row depending in some way or other neighboring rows.

Comment: I think pandas dataframes are not a helpful data structure for you here. Your best bet is probably to convert your dataframe to a 2d list or matrix, and then use numba's just-in-time-compilation decorator on your nested loop. You'll have to modify it a bit but not so much

Comment: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html

Answer (score 1):

Often where balances like inventory are involved 'vectorisation' can be achieved using cumulative for the flows.

iterative `balance[t] = balance[t-1] + in[t] - out[t]` becomes vectorised `balance = in.cumsum() - out.cumsum()`

```
import numpy as np

in_ = np.array( [10, 5, 30, 20, 10, 50, 5, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0] )
orders = np.array( [0, 0, 0,  0, 70, 0, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] )
# 4 extra periods to handle the out of date range.

out_of_date = np.zeros_like( in_ )
out_of_date[ 4: ] = in_[ :-4 ]
# Parts fall out of date after 4 weeks if not already delivered.

# Create cumulatives to work with
cum_in = in_.cumsum()           # Constant through calculation
cum_orders = orders.cumsum()    # Constant through calculation
cum_ood = out_of_date.cumsum()  # Amended at each iteration
cum_deliveries = np.zeros_like( cum_in ) # One period filled each iteration 
available = np.zeros_like( in_ )         # One period filled each iteration
deliveries = np.zeros_like( cum_in )     # One period filled each iteration

def decum( in_, axis=-1 ):
    """ Take differences in_[t] - in_[t-1] fill first period with in_[0] """
    res = in_.copy()
    res[ 1: ] = np.diff(in_, 1, axis = axis)
    return res

def cum_dels( week ):
    """ Calcultes cumulative deliveries at the week specified.
        Also calculates the value of deliveries in the week """
    available[ week ] = cum_in[ week ] - cum_ood[ week ]
    cum_deliveries[ week ] = np.minimum( cum_orders[ week ], available[ week ] )
    if week:
        deliveries[ week ] = cum_deliveries[ week ] - cum_deliveries[ week-1 ]
    else:
        deliveries[ week ] = cum_deliveries[ week ]  # If week == 0 no difference to take

def amend_ood( week ):
    """ Amend the cum_ood for deliveries in the week. """
    min_cum_ood = cum_ood[ week ]    # Don't subtract to below the cum_ood in this week.
    available_notused = available[ week ] - cum_deliveries[ week ] 
    # Don't subtract any available that's not delivered. 
    # This has the effect of taking deliveries from the most recent in_

    max_subtract = np.maximum( cum_ood[ week: ] - min_cum_ood - available_notused, 0)
    # The maximum to subtract is the cum_ood less the fixed bands and never less than zero.

    to_subtract = np.minimum( max_subtract, deliveries[ week ] ) # max_subtract clipped at the weeks deliveries
    cum_ood[ week: ] -= to_subtract

week_range = range(8)

# Iterate the above functions by week.  
# This can be rewritten to calculate all part numbers for each week.
for week in week_range:
    cum_dels( week )
    amend_ood( week )

print(deliveries)
print(decum(cum_ood)[4:])
```

The functions need to be rewritten to work with 2d arrays, part_number x week.  Then each iteration by week calculates all part numbers for that week.

I'll look at making it 2d once I've some time but this may help as is.  There's also certain to be scope to optimise the code. It's written to help me understand what I was doing.

**Edit Changes to run a 2D version **

```
out_of_date = np.zeros_like( in_ )
out_of_date[ :, 4: ] = in_[ :, :-4 ]
# Parts fall out of date after 4 weeks if not already delivered.

# Create cumulatives to work with
cum_in = in_.cumsum(axis=1)           # Constant through calculation
cum_orders = orders.cumsum(axis=1)    # Constant through calculation
cum_ood = out_of_date.cumsum(axis=1)  # Amended at each iteration
cum_deliveries = np.zeros_like( cum_in ) # One period filled each iteration 
available = np.zeros_like( in_ )         # One period filled each iteration
deliveries = np.zeros_like( cum_in )     # One period filled each iteration
def decum( in_, axis=-1 ):
    """ Take differences in_[t] - in_[t-1] fill first period with in_[0] """
    res = in_.copy()
    res[ :, 1: ] = np.diff(in_, 1, axis = axis)
    return res

def cum_dels( week ):
    """ Calcultes cumulative deliveries at the week specified.
        Also calculates the value of deliveries in the week """
    available[ :, week ] = cum_in[ :, week ] - cum_ood[ :, week ]
    cum_deliveries[ :, week ] = np.minimum( cum_orders[ :, week ], available[ :, week ] )
    if week:
        deliveries[ :, week ] = cum_deliveries[ :, week ] - cum_deliveries[ :, week-1 ]
    else:
        deliveries[ :, week ] = cum_deliveries[ :, week ]  # If week == 0 no difference to take

def amend_ood( week ):
    """ Amend the cum_ood for deliveries in the week. """
    min_cum_ood = cum_ood[ :, week ]    # Don't subtract to below the cum_ood in this week.
    available_notused = available[ :, week ] - cum_deliveries[ :, week ] 
    # Don't subtract any available that's not delivered. 
    # This has the effect of taking deliveries from the most recent in_

    max_subtract = np.maximum( cum_ood[ :, week: ] - min_cum_ood[:,None] - available_notused[:,None], 0)
    # The maximum to subtract is the cum_ood less the fixed bands and never less than zero.

    to_subtract = np.minimum( max_subtract, deliveries[ :, week ].reshape(-1,1) ) # max_subtract clipped at the weeks deliveries
    cum_ood[ :, week: ] -= to_subtract
```

This doesn't give the same results as your version for part number Z.

What results are expected with the following scenarios?

```
data = {                                                                                
    "Part": ["Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"],                                                  
    "Week": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],                                                            
    "Gross Forecast": [10, 5, 10, 30, 30, 0],                                 
    "Orders":          [ 0, 0, 0, 0, -90, 0]                                  
}
```

Or this

```
data = {                                             
    "Part": ["Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"],
    "Week": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8],                  
    "Gross Forecast": [10, 5, 10, 30, 30, 0, 0, 100],
    "Orders":          [ 0,-90, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, -50]
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what should happen in several cases where the results (of the pandas implementation) don't look to be consistent. 2 exceptional scenarios shown at the bottom of the answer.